# Shouldn't this answer about Marcion's gospel be converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/9290/2757) saying that it doesn't address the question and should be converted to a comment, but my flag was rejected saying that a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it.

This really does seem like a straight forward case of answering instead of commenting. The question is about the Muratorian Fragment not Marcion's gospel, which just happens to be included in the quote.

Instead of reflagging I thought I'd post on meta. Is my thinking good, or does this somehow qualify as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, I'm the mod that rejected the flag and I'll explain my thinking in an answer, but I may not have time today so I hope you don't mind waiting?

Comment: Whenever you have time, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember being slightly surprised at this flag, the answer seems well-informed, and appears to cast doubt on a foundational assumption of the question: "This is attested by the early heretic Marcion".

One careful re-read later and I see that this is (presumably) a partial quotation of a list A, B, C... and Z, where A is the 'evidence' of the Marcion Gospel and B is the Muratorian Fragment and so on. The OP is only asking about B, and A is only quoted because it would be difficult to remove it and leave the quote making grammatical sense.

In other words I see now that you are right, the question is not about the Marcion Gospel at all and fdb's answer which only addresses A is technically not an answer (to this question), but rather a comment.

I've made a minor edit to the question to emphasize this, and converted the answer to a comment. I've also asked a *new* question [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/11515/43) which is directly about part A! I'm hoping fdb will post his answer there :)

Thanks for bringing this up on meta in such a constructive way (much better than re-flagging, please never do that!), and please keep up the good work flagging, editing, asking and answering questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes perfect sense.